# Create a Map from List of Objects using Java 8 stream where the the key of map needs to be conditional

Tags: java, list, dictionary, conditional-statements, java-stream

I would like to create a `Map<String, Employee>` from `List<Employee>` where the key of the map will be `empId` if it's not `null` but if `empId` is `null` the key of the map will be `empName`.
So the key of the map will be a `non null` value of either of the two.

```java
Employee {
private String empId;
private String empName;
}
```

Comment: With little research you can find below
   ```Employee e1 = new Employee("1", "E1");
    Employee e2 = new Employee("2", "E2");
    List<Employee> employeeList = Arrays.asList(e1, e2);
    Map result = employeeList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(employee -> {
      return null != employee.getId() ? employee.getId(): employee.getName()
    }, e-> e));```

Answer (score 2):

You could have a custom key mapper that checks whether the `empId` is `null` or not:

```
Map<String, Employee> employeeMap = employeeList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
    e -> e.empId != null ? e.empId : e.empName,
    Function.identity()
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Why tricky? Select one or the other:

```
final Map<String, Employee> map = employees.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(
      e -> Objects.toString(e.getEmpId(), e.getEmpName()),
      Function.identity()));
```

`Objects#toString(Object, String)` takes two arguments: if the first one is null, the second will be used as fallback/default value.

With Java 9 (11?) there's also `Objects#requireNonNullOrElse` (and `Objects#requireNonNullOrElseGet`) which will throw an exception if the second argument is null.

If your input contains duplicated employee ids or names, you can provide a third argument to the `toMap` collector to define the *merge strategy*:

```
Collectors.toMap(..., ..., (a, b) -> a); // keep first
Collectors.toMap(..., ..., (a, b) -> b); // last wins
// or any other strategy you can think of
```

The default strategy is to throw an exception.

Comment: This is correct, however I am not a fan of spoonfeeding answers where no attempt was made by OP to solve the task themselves.